# vb.net referring to a program-created form via New

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have the following code in vb.net written in a button.

```
dim x as new frm_raw_infosheet
```

whenever I click on the button, the program does create a new instance of the form which is what I want.

My question is, how will I be able to refer to each one of those newly created forms? 
for example, I clicked the button 3 times, how will I programmatically hide the 2nd form I created with the button?

I tried

```
x.name = "Form" & incrementingvariable
```

however, I'm not entirely sure how I'm going to refer to it.

To make my question more clear, let's say incrementingvariable contains the number 2

```
incrementingvariable = 2
```

x now contains the name "Form2"

however, this returns an error

```
Form2.enabled = false
```

I can't refer to Form2, Because .Net Says that "Form2" doesn't exist!

**EDIT**

I understand it's been a while since I asked this, but here is an update

On the listboxes are the literal names of each form which I stored using `Listbox1.items.add(x.Name)`.

How do I call an instance in the collection then? Say I want to make a form in the list visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to the edited question: Instead of adding the names of the forms to the ListBox, you can add the Form objects themselves:

```
Listbox1.Items.Add(x)
```

If you set the `DisplayMember` property of the ListBox to Name, the name of the form is displayed in the listbox (as it was before). 
Now you are able to access the form object directly through the ListBox' Items collection and call methods on them:

```
DirectCast(ListBox1.Items(2), Form).Enabled = False
```

This example accesses the third form in the ListBox (of course you will want to make sure you do not access an index that is not present; the Count property is helpful in this respect).
As the items are stored as objects, you have to cast them to a Form object before you can access members that are defined in the Form class.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want your program to work.

If you're only going to have one instance of the form open at any time you can save the reference returned by `new` in a persistent variable, e.g. an instance variable. You could then refer to the old form and close it at any later time.

If you need to keep track of more than one form then you could save the reference returned by `new` in a collection, which could also be an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Marcus! Exactly how do you declare an instance variable thoug? how will you refer to it? I mean, let's say I created this instance variable, how will I change its' text property? 
.Net's intellisense kicks in when I type in a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim frmMyForm As frm_raw_infosheet
Dim i as Integer = 0

For Each frm As Form in Application.OpenForms
    If frm.Name = "frm_raw_infosheet" Then
        i = i + 1
        If i = 2 Then
            frmMyForm = frm
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

If i = 2 Then
    frmMyForm.Visible = False
End If
```