# Dynamic timers with dynamic Ticks

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, timer

**Point 1:**
Is possible make a dynamic timer with dynamic event Ticks on VB?

Ok, I know how I can make a new timer, and I know how I can add a Event, with:

```
AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
AddHandler Timer2.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
.
.
AddHandler TimerN.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
```

With N integer.

But I want that the Event is dynamic, then I need know something of the present timer, like a name of the timer for know which variables I need to use in each case.

Easy example:

```
Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

MsgBox(Show the name of present timer)

End Sub
```

Ok, maybe there is other form, but I am newbie. My work final is: Create dynamic timers, each time will have a particular Event.Tick with similar structure, but different variables.

**Point 2:**
I need change the interval of present timer too.

Easy example:

```
Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

MsgBox(Show the name of present timer)

TimerPresent.Interval = XXXXX

End Sub
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Malky.Kid.

Now I have it:

```
AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
AddHandler Timer2.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
.
.
AddHandler TimerN.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

Public Sub TickingFunction(ByVal TheTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer, ByVal newInterval As Integer)

    MsgBox(TheTimer.Name?????)
    TheTimer.Interval = newInterval

End Sub

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    TickingFunction(sender, SomeInterval)

End Sub
```

Just I need know how I can know the name of timer, or something for recognize the present timer.

Thanks!

Comment: I have visual basic 2012, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that VBA means Visual Basic.

Comment: @eKeR VBA [is an implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) in VB6 used in applications like Excel macros. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info

Comment: @SysDragon thanks for your reply, it is now clear to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the project you are aiming for?

Perhaps you can create a common subroutine, which from there you can manipulate their respective variables whenever you call it

```
Public Sub TickingFunction(byval TheTimer as Timer, byval newInterval as integer)
    MsgBox(TheTimer.Name.Tostring)
    TheTimer.Interval = newInterval
End Sub
```

Now you can call it with your corresponding timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     Dim newINterval as integer = 0
     TickingFunction(Timer1, newInterval)
End Sub
```

**Note** just switch newInterval with a value of your new interval. My advice is to use a public variable (not contained within a subroutine) for dynamic-ability.

Comment: But I will have N (natural number) of timers (I dont know the N number, this will grow or decrease). I can not make N number of Events.Tick. I want make N timers and that each timer has the same Event.Tick structure, but diferent variables inside. For example: New timer1 has var "Hello", New timer2 has var "Bye", then when the timer1 call a tick event, I show Hello, when the timer2 call the same tick event, then I show Bye. How? For example with dicctionary, "timer1" = "hello", "timer2" = "bye". Then I just need know the name of timer inside the event. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to program, friend?

Comment: Ok, I need add task with timers for check a link of web for each timer, It must have a diferent interval that depend of dates of the web. Every timer do the same, but with different link, and I need change sometimes the interval of the timer that check a link. I need make something for add N timers (with 1 link each timer). For it, I need that every timer fire the same event.tick with different variables. I dont know if I explained well :P. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you need to CAST these timers from a container. Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870811/vb-net-referring-to-a-program-created-form-via-new) except treat the FORMS as Timers.

Comment: Also, don't forget to let me know if this has helped you.

Comment: Great!! But, I dont know how I can get the name of Timer, or something, I will EDIT my question

Answer (score 2):

Finally I get my solution:

Thanks to **Malky.Kid**. It is a little edited that how he did

Now I have it:

```
AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
AddHandler Timer2.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
.
.
AddHandler TimerN.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
```

For each timer, you can define TimerN.Tag = "SomeID", TimerN.Interval = X Integer

```
Public Sub TickingFunction(ByVal TheTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer, ByVal newInterval As Integer)

    MsgBox(TheTimer.Tag) 'this gives the name/tag of timer
    TheTimer.Interval = newInterval 

End Sub
```

Every timer fired here, but each timer is a different object that call to the same function

```
Private Sub OnTimedEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    TickingFunction(sender, SomeInterval)

End Sub
```